# Dash Plotly, unable to download the processed excel file on button click

Tags: python, html, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build small dash App that lets the user download an Excel that is generated through the following function:

```
import base64
import io
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc,html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
app = dash.Dash()
app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Convertion of FMS logdata to parced data'),
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.B('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),

    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Button("Download xlsx", id="btn"),
            dcc.Download(id="download")])
])
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), skiprows=8, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11])

    return html.Div([
        html.P('Analog Input2 with Respect to Timestamp'),

        dcc.Graph(
             figure=px.scatter(df2, x="Speed", y="Longitude")),
    ])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

from this script I can able to plot the graph but I am unable to download the excel file of processed data on button click how can i do that any suggestions.
i used this data this is my data i used https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QqiiAPLu7xU2BVOy3K4m0cjLIv0HsmHrrKnZMilfjgk/edit?usp=sharing and following snippet i got [image: unable to download file on button click]

Comment: What is the relation between the plot and the Excel file? The plot and CSV file ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a callback, try adding the following:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("download", "data"),
    [Input("btn", "n_clicks")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def func(n_clicks):
    return dcc.send_data_frame(df2.to_csv, "mydf.csv")
```

Comment: or if you want to stick with `xls` files, change the return to `return dcc.send_data_frame(df2.to_excel, "mydf2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet_name_1")`

Comment: by adding above call back getting  error "id not found in layout"

Comment: I just edited the answer, I had one too many argument in the `func`

Comment: You need to add `global df2` in `def parse_contents` to make it work.

Comment: @hoatran yes i strucked on that where can i add it as global variable

Comment: getting error because of that only

Comment: @hoatran,thanks for the suggestion now I got output

Comment: @Mat.B thank you so much my script working fine now

Comment: @AparnaAppu: so you should mark Mat.B answer as right one.

Comment: yes, marked that